# How to Change LocalHost URL in VS Code

Tags: url, visual-studio-code, localhost, umbraco

I just installed Umbraco for testing purposes on my local computer. I installed it using Visual Studio Code.

I'm having trouble finding the spot to redirect the url from "localhost:1111" to a custom domain like "umbraco.dev".

I have already changed my host file and added the site in IIS. Where do i make the connection in VSCode? It doesn't appear to be the same as regular Visual Studio.